# JSP page for loop in row

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have made the following code

```
<%ArrayList<Doc> std = 
            (ArrayList<Doc>)request.getAttribute("doclist");
        for(Doc s:std){%>
        
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><%=s.getId()%></h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
    
    
        
        
            <%}%>
```

I get my cards like
Card 1
Card 2
Card 3
Card 4
Card 5

like wise for the number of data available

I want to have my cards display 4 per each row like
Card 1 Card 2 Card 3 Card 4 
Card 5

How is it possible to do. im passing the data form a servlet

Comment: this has nothing to do with Java, but rather with your UI

Comment: 1. Use a normal for loop `for(int i...` instead of an enhanced loop; 2. make (and then close at the end) a `div` only when `i % 4 == 0`

Comment: Can you please write an answer im new to jsp pages

Comment: @user15520720 this is just the logic, this has little to do with jsp or otherwise. The comment of Federico tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: @user15520720 it's a bit hard to tell you *exactly* what to do because it depends on how your html is structured. I don't know what a `card` class implies in terms of presentation and I don't know how CSS rules may affect the result visually.

Comment: JSP is in the context of this question indeed merely a HTML page generator. For questions about HTML and CSS themselves, you should ignore any server side code (JSP/PHP/JSF/ASP/etc/etc) and focus on the generated HTML output as you can find via right-click, *View Page Source* in a normal web browser. Because, you would have faced exactly the same problem when you copypaste that generated HTML output into a plain vanilla `test.html` file and open it in a webbrowser. I have adjusted your question accordingly.

Comment: This is jsp question someone edited it completely

Comment: Nope. You don't have a problem with JSP. Your JSP code is working perfectly fine. You have only a problem with the produced HTML output. See previous comment for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of job comes under UI category.

You use below css for your reference:

```
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        margin-left: 5em;
        margin-right: 5em;
    }
    .ele {
        border: 1px black solid;
    }
```

Refer this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68O6eOGAGqA

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<Div style="display:inline">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 4</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 5</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
</Div>
```